# Best way to convert Java/Scala Char using Apache Thrift

Tags: java, scala, thrift

I need to use Apache Thrift for defining common data structures to be shared between several Scala microservices with the help of Apache Kafka or direct RPC calls.

I'm wondering what's the best way to define a [Scala Char type](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Char.html) in Thrift, considering that:

> Char, a **16-bit unsigned integer** (equivalent to Java's char primitive type) is a subtype of scala.AnyVal. Instances of Char are not represented by an object in the underlying runtime system.

In the [Apache Thrift types](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/types) there's nothing about unsigned integers:

> **Note the absence of unsigned integer types**. This is due to the fact that there are no native unsigned integer types in many programming languages.

I have to define a Thrift struct that will map this Scala case class:

```scala
case class Grade(letter: Char, low: Option[Double], high: Option[Double])
```

So the question now is how should I map `letter: Char`?

```
struct Grade {
    1: unsigned i16 letter // <- THIS IS CLEARLY WRONG
    2: optional double low
    3: optional double high
}
```

Comment: I guess the agreed sane approach is to define a separate DTO structure which implements whatever is required by the protocol and existing libraries and then implement manually bidirectional mapping: Domain <-> DTO. So store this char as int or byte array or single-letter string, and just parse DTO object into domain object when you receive it. It's the same principle whether you use Thrift, JSON, gRPC, Protobuffs, Avro and what not.

Comment: Even defining a new DTO the main question is still what's the best way to define an unsigned integer type.

Comment: It doesn't matter that much. From Scala-side you still need to parse it and there is virtually 0 difference from what you will parse it. From Thrift-side each approach might have some overhead though, which one has the smallest can be only determined by a benchmark for your data, which nobody is going to do for you as it's way too use-case specific.

Comment: Well, I mean I can even store it as a string, but I was looking for suggestions on how to define an unsigned 16-bit integer using Thrift. I guess that this case should be covered in detail because it should be a common problem, considering that we're talking about a native Java/Scala type.

Answer (score 0):

Given the options we have there is basically two ways to do it:

1. use the next larger signed type instead, so that the unisgned will fit in
2. cast the unsigned values from and to signed

While binary protocol will transmit all 32 bits even if half of them is not really used, `TCompactProtocol` for example does not. So whether or not "wire efficiency" is affected is more a question of what protocols are actually used, rather than the data type.

That being said, using an binary or string as BLOB container to transport arbitrary data is surely also something that works, but in that case you are essentially "doing it yourself" with all negative effects that go along with such an approach. I don't tell you to not do it, I just want to explicitly mention that fact.